# WPF: MSVS 2010 and Blend. Will Studio designer replace Blend soon?

Tags: wpf

I started to play (just play, not to produce real life projects) with WPF since MSVS 2008 where WPF built-in designer (as far as I can remember) was extremely poor so if I wanted to create layout I had to dive deep into XAML tags. So I treated Expression Blend as temporary application developed to overcome limitations of MSVS those days.

MSVS 2010 provides much more powerfull designer so I forgot about Blend at all.

Is there Microsoft vision on Blend and MSVS designer as rival products, will designer replace Blend one day or any other vision how these products will share the market in the closest future?

May I treat MSVS WPF designer vs Blend evolution as MSVS intellisence compared to ReSharper one?

Answer (score 7):

Blend is for more complicated designs, like storyboards and visual state managers etc, which is not possible currently in visual studio. Visual Studio provides basic functionality of editing needed for business/crud apps, but for high class animation and better rich graphics results, Visual Studio will never replace Blend.

For graphics designers, intellisense is of very low importance then richness in the graphics editor. Blend is for designing Themes, color schemes. Visual Studio is for writing code and business apps.

Comment: Thank you, @Akash. But Studio designer continue to evolve, do you think it will compete Blend with new designer-oriented capabilities one day?

Comment: No it will not, the audience is different, people who will work on Blend will come from graphics/flash designer people. VS designer will not support animation, vector drawing, effects programming. VS designer will focus on data programming, binding etc.